# How Do I Use Selenium WebDriver To Click A Non Anchor Tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to do automated testing of a website. I have been successful in clicking through numerous menus and links to a point.

At one point the website I am working with generates links that look like this:

```
<U onclick="HourglassSubmitItem(document.all('PageName').value, '00000001Responsibility Code')">Responsibility Code</U>
```

I am trying to use the .click functionality of the webdriver to click this link with no success.

Using this:

```
page.find_element_by_xpath("//u[contains(text(),'Responsibility Code')]")
```

successfully finds the U tag above. but when I add .click() to the end of this xpath, the click is not performed. But it also does not generate an error. So, my question is can Selenium be used to simulate clicks on an HTML tag that is NOT an anchor () tag? If so, how?

I will also say that I do not have control over the page I am working with, so changing the  to  is not possible.

I would appreciate any guidance the Community could provide.

Thank You for you help,

Chris

Comment: It might be worth trying to click the surrounding tags, or nearby tags that are in the same position as this element, just in case one of those is the one that's supposed to receive the click

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using `JavaScript` could solve the "clicking" issue:

```
element = page.find_element_by_xpath("//u[contains(text(),'Responsibility Code')]")
page.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer JavaScript in this case.

```
WebElment  element = page.find_element_by_xpath("//u[contains(text(),'Responsibility Code')]")

JavaScriptExecutor executor = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;

executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```